# Best procedure for dealing with memory warnings after losing opengl context

Tags: iphone, memory-management, opengl-es, ios4

I've been chasing a bug in my game, I think i finally found the problem.

I have a memory management routine that gets called on memory warnings, it basically checks what is loaded and not needed, and releases that.
Most of my memory is being used in textures for opengl, such that besides textures I only need to dump a few objects to keep the system happy even on a 3G with it's limited memory.

Now my problem, on a few occasions I lose the openGL context, when playing a movie with MPMoviePlayerController for example, or when calling the GC system views.

A few times the loading of the GC or MPMovie will coincide with my memory management routine being called, this is what I think is crashing the game, since I don't have the opengl context, I get:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x471c9080: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

when trying to glDeleteTextures.

Now I'm changing my code so I don't try to delete textures on an invalid context (still checking how to do that), but I'm still left with the problem of what to do when I get a memory warning during a opengl context blackout.

I see only one option

1. Before calling something that will make me lose context try and release memory

I don't particularly like this option because it introduces lag on some operations.

1. Anybody see a better way ?
2. Is my analisys of the problem correct ? (Do I really lose opengl context when using MPlayer and GC)
3. Any other way to release the textures ?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Well, it certainly sounds like there are at least a couple basic preventative steps you can take here:

1. You should keep a reference to your `EAGLContext` around. This will allow you to make your context current to operate on (delete) its textures at any time necessary. (You shouldn't be calling `glDeleteTextures` at some random time if you're not sure your context is current.)
2. You can check to see if your context is current with: `if (myContext == [EAGLContext currentContext])...`. You could choose to do no memory flushing when this is not true, or take other actions depending on its status.

Comment: I do have a reference to my EAGLContext, setting it current when an MPPlayer movie was playing stopped the movie and made it disappear. The current context comparison hadn't occurred to me, but of course it works, thx. Still need to find a way to delete those textures...